# Access Let Get with QAxBase (Qt)

Tags: qt, vb6, activex

I successfully can access Get method of class by ActiveX, but can't access Let property.

```
QAxObject *p = new QAxObject( "MyApp.Application", 0 );
p->dynamicCall("Signals(const QString& )","Sig0");// this will issue GET
p->dynamicCall("Signals(const QString& ,int)","Sig0",1);// doesn't work
```

VB code :

```
Public Property Get Signal(ByVal Key As Variant) As Long
Debug.Print Key
End Property

Public Property Let Signal(ByVal Key As Variant, ByVal Value As Long)
Debug.Print Key _ Value
End Property
```

My goal is to issue Let method.

Comment: How does that COM object typelibrary look like?

Comment: There are two items:   

[id(00000000), propget]   
long Signal([in] VARIANT Key);   

[id(00000000), propput]  
void Signal(  
                [in] VARIANT Key,   
                [in] long rhs);

Comment: You use "Signals". Plural? The interface shows singular "Signal". And maybe p->dynamicCall("Signals(const QString& ,int)","Sig0",1); should be p->dynamicCall("Signal(const QString& ,long)","Sig0",1); then.

Comment: I know . it can be translated to OBJ->SIGNALS->SIGNAL("something")  it doesn't matter The question is how to run Second "propput". When I use dynamic call I always get propget.

Comment: QAxObject *p = new QAxObject( "MyApp.Application", 0 );
p = p->querySubObject("Signals");
p->dynamicCall("Signal(const QString& ,int)","Sig0",1);// doesn't work

Comment: I only do Qt's own dumpcpp and then use the imported definitions in my projects. There problems and glitches with it but it is not run-time but compilable solution for interfaces and more like ATL. I also mix code with ATL by putting ATL #import in a separate module when I cannot get Qt's import to work. Also, please try to put "long" instead of "int" in the string Qt definition for the "put" method.

Comment: I tried. I should glance at QAxBase dynamicCall source . Because I suspect that dynamicCall executes only the first occurrence

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use IDispatch method.
Problem was that Qt library assumes that property Set(PUT) accepts only one parameter but in my case I need Put with two parameters.
this article helped me to solve it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216686